# unexpected end of file

Tags: shell

Have written a small script for our Windows machine but getting the below mentioned error.
syntax error: unexpected end of file.Can you please help me to resolve it. I have attached only part of my script.

```
if [ -s $final ]; then
a=`cat $final`
else
a=NULL
echo $a > $final
fi
echo $a
```

Comment: There are many minor problems here (quoting, backticks), but none of them should result in such error, so main problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What happens if you run the script that you posted?

Comment: The error is in the part you didn't post. Make sure that your script has Unix line endings (i.e. LF only, not CR+LF).

Answer (score 1):

Such an error is usually caused by a missing quote or missing `fi`, `done`, etc.

As you don't show your whole script it's not possible to say what exactly is wrong. The snippet shown is mostly OK (besides formatting issues). I would add double quotes `"` around the `$final` however as that may go wrong if there are spaces in `$final`.